# What is the quickest way to get ssl running on apache2 on ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, ssl

I want to set up ssl for apache 2. How can I do it the quickest way?

Comment: your question and answer are identical - this is *not* a question/answer format.  Your question needs to be a question while your answer needs to be an answer.  Otherwise it doesn't fit into the format.

Comment: ok. I fixed it.

Comment: This is not a question ...

Comment: Look, i came up  with this because when I googled setting up "ssl on apache2 ubuntu" I knew there was something better than what came up. there are a lot of applications that won't work on apache unless it is running ssl. I am just trying "to do unto others" with this post. This more about the content than the form. Does it work or not? It works. Most how tos describe setting up self-signed certificate which is unnecessary. If you're in a hurry you can do it my way below.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide the answer since i couldn't find it anywhere else. i challenge anyone to come up with a simpler faster answer.

1. a2enmod ssl
2. a2ensite default-ssl.conf
3. sudo service restart apache2
4. voila ssl

(There has been a built-in snake-oil certificate since forever so you don't have to bother going through the process of creating a self-signed certificate which is described in most how tos. Of course if you want to get a certificate from a reccognized authority use Letsencrypt.)